# libpqcrypto python implementation

Tags: python, c, post-quantum-cryptography

I am trying to use the python API in libpqcrypto (https://libpqcrypto.org/index.html). I followed the installation and was able to import it to python but I get an error when I try to run the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PQimport.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pqcrypto
  File "/home/libpqcrypto/libpqcrypto-20180314/python/pqcrypto.py", line 218
    %crypto_hash: x += [('PRIMITIVE',CRYPTO_BYTES)]
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I address this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as some information on your environment.

Comment: After following the instructions on the website, I exported the path to the library to python using export PYTHONPATH=/home/libpqcrypto/libpqcrypto-20180314/python. Then I wrote a python program that imports pqcrypto and prints done if there are no errors (This was just to test the import). The program was written on a Ubuntu 18.04 vm.

Comment: @chandramoulipranav, have you resolved the problem?